How to get data from django database model
What I did:
views.py
class CandidateView(View):
   
   def get(self, request, **kwargs):
      pk = kwargs['pk']
      candidates = Resume.objects.get(pk=pk)

      posts = Post.objects.all().values()
      post_contents = []
      for post in posts:
            if isinstance(post, dict) :  
                continue
            elif isinstance(post, Post):
                post_contents.append(post.content)

      return render(request, 'blog/candidate.html', {'candidate':candidates, 'posts': post_contents})

models.py
class Resume(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
 gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 locality = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 pin = models.PositiveIntegerField()
 state = models.CharField(choices=STATE_CHOICE, max_length=50)
 mobile = models.PositiveIntegerField()
 email = models.EmailField()
 job_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profileimg', blank=True)
 my_file = models.FileField(upload_to='doc', blank=True)
 blog_post = models.CharField(max_length=100000)
 
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', null=True, blank=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

I'm new to Django and I want to get my blog content from Post model to CandidateView.
Main idea is getting all the blog content and showing it into resume.
but I cant figure it out how to do it or what I am doing wrong.

The main issue is this Post.objects.all().values() call, specifically the .values(), if you remove it than your code should work. .values() returns a list of dicts, so right now you are continuing when it's a dict which is the main problem
All of these solutions would work. You should more than likely do Solution 4 and pass the actual Post objects to the template that way you can access other attributes like title
Solution 1
Remove .values (loop through Post objects)
posts = Post.objects.all()
post_contents = []
for post in posts:
    post_contents.append(post.content)

Solution 2
use .values (loop through list of dicts)
posts = Post.objects.all().values()
post_contents = []
for post in posts:
    post_contents.append(post["content"])

Solution 3
use .values "correctly" by passing the field. Then flat=True to remove the loop
post_contents = Post.objects.all().values("content", flat=True)

Outputs for #3
with flat=true
post_contents = ["content1", "content2"]

without flat=true (would require a loop like #2)
post_contents = [{"content": "content1"}, {"content": "content2"}]

Solution 4
pass the Post objects themselves to the view (preferred)
data = {
    'candidate':candidates,
    'posts': Post.objects.all()
}
return render(request, 'blog/candidate.html', data)

View for #4
Loop through posts inside the template
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.content }}
    {{ post.title }}
{% endif %}

